# D2O distribution in water

Tags: nuclear-physics, water, earth, isotopes, oceanography

I just learned that about 1/1000 of hydrogen is deuterium. Does that mean 1/1000 of water is D2O, which is heavier and sinks to the bottom in a glass of water? And consequently is there a layer of D2O at the bottom of the ocean?
thanks!

Comment: Duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69930/

Answer (score 3):

It's rarer than that, more like 1 in 6000.  Because each molecule of water has two atoms of hydrogen, then about every 2 in 6000 (1 in 3000) has a single atom of deuterium (DHO).  And would be closer to 1 in every 6000$^2$ for a molecule of D2O.

The linked question [Deuterium density in seawater](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/deuterium-density-in-seawater) gives sources that show deuterium is well-mixed in the ocean.  The difference in weight between D2O and H2O is similar to the difference in weight of N2 and O2.  Currents, turbulence, and diffusion are sufficient to keep those molecules well distributed in our atmosphere, so I would not expect separation of D2O to occur spontaneously in water.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer

Comment: In the spirit of John Rennie's comment you could add "No, it doesn't sink, either in the ocean or in a glass of water." to your answer and make it complete.

Comment: And as one of the few people who have tasted pure D2O I can attest it tastes just like regular water!

Comment: @DirkBruere And when did you taste pure D2O?  A few seconds ago?  Maybe you should go to a hospital.  o_O

Comment: @Neil About 20 years ago. It's not very toxic, just very expensive :-)

Comment: @DirkBruere That's interesting.  Thanks for sharing.  In exchange I'll tell you one myself.  In the movies, they show that injecting someone with air is deadly, and almost every nurse injecting a patient dies within seconds.  My mother teaches nursing and regularly injects herself with air to prove that air isn't removed from needles prior to  injection for *that* reason but to ensure that the proper dosage is given and for no other reason.  The reaction by the students, my mother says, are priceless.  ;)